# Combining a digital and a physical version of the same product (without making 2 different nodes/products) using Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I have been struggling for weeks now to find the best solution for the following problem.

Suppose I am a filmmaker and want to sell my films on DVD, Blu Ray, but also as a digital download. Without having to create 3 different products.

I suppose for the two physical objects (choice between DVD or blu ray), I could use a product option. But how to combine it with something only virtual (so no shipping fees, ..) ? Any thoughts what the best way to tackle this would be?

Thanks kind internet stranger!

Answer (score 0):

I would add the digital download as another product option after the DVD and BluRay. Then alter the option’s weight so it’s zero. Then I would create rules that allow for the access or sending a downloadable link once the checkout is complete. Also have a think about how you want to handle a cart that has both physical and digital products together.